# MySQL - Pivot rows to comma separated values

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot-table, crosstab

I have 3 tables.

```
1. user
2. user_role
3. user_role_mapping
```

**Sample record,**

**user**

```
+--------+----------+---------------+
| userid | username | email         |
+--------+----------+---------------+
|      1 | user1    |user1@test.com |
|      2 | user2    |user2@test.com |
+--------+----------+---------------+
```

**user_role**

```
+--------+----------+
| roleid | rolename |
+--------+----------+
|      1 | user     |
|      2 | manager  |
|      3 | director |
|      4 | admin    |
+--------+----------+
```

**User_role_mapping**

```
+--------+------+
| roleid |userid|
+--------+------+
|      1 | 1    |
|      2 | 1    |
|      3 | 1    |
+--------+------+
```

**Query**

```
select u.userid, u.username, u.email,
  count(case when ur.rolename = 'user' THEN 1 END) user,
  count(case when ur.rolename = 'manager' THEN 1 END) manager,
  count(case when ur.rolename = 'director' THEN 1 END) director,
  count(case when ur.rolename = 'admin' THEN 1 END) admin
from user_role ur
left join userrole_mapping urm
  on ur.roleid = urm.roleid
left join user u
  on urm.userid = u.userid
group by u.userid, u.username, u.email
```

**Result:-**

```
+--------+----------+---------------+------|---------|----------|-------|
| userid | username | email         | user | manager | director | admin |
+--------+----------+---------------+------------------------------------
|      1 | user1    |user1@test.com | 1    |   1     |  1       |  1    |
+--------+----------+---------------+------------------------------------
```

Here, I am hardcoding the role in the query and the new role can get added in the future and I do not want to do the code change. Is there any better approach? I am fine with comma separated result for role in the result.

Comment: `count(case when ur.rolename = 'role' THEN 1 END)` can be simplified to `SUM(ur.rolename = 'role')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For comma separation you can use [group_concat](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
select u.user_id, u.user_name, u.email,
       Group_concat(ur.role_name) roles
from user u
left join user_role_mapping urm
  on urm.user_id = u.user_id
left join user_role ur
  on ur.role_id = urm.role_id
where u.user_id = ?
group by u.user_id;
```

Another, maybe better approach w/o hardcoding would be to query the roles separately:

```
select u.user_id, u.user_name, u.email, ur.role_name
from user u
left join user_role_mapping urm
  on urm.user_id = u.user_id
left join user_role ur
  on ur.role_id = urm.role_id
where u.user_id = ?;
```